# How to output different values in a single record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have a value in a string form. The field name is `CF$_LMWEQUIMENT` and the output is a single string separated by `^`. Here is an example:

```
^All_Equipm^Consulting^DITCHCLEANER^Friction_M^
```

I need to output the real values this way of the the database value like this:

```
All Equipment, Consulting, Ditch Cleaner, Friction Management.
```

I have this query to get `CF$_LMWEQUIMENT`

```
SELECT T1.OPPORTUNITY_NO AS BO_NUMBER,
       T2.CF$_LMWEQUIMENT AS Equiment_Group,
       T1.STATE AS Status
FROM BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY T1 JOIN 
BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY_CFT T2 on (T1.OBJKEY = T2.ROWKEY)
```

I have the API that can transform to the real value, for instance:

```
select custom_field_enum_values_api.Get_Client_Value('EQUIGROLMW','DITCHCLEANER') 
from dual;
```

The output from the API will be `Ditch Cleaner`. However, my goal is to have all the values in a single string and cell such as I explained in my previous paragraph -> `All Equipment, Consulting, Ditch Cleaner, Friction Management`.

You can notice in the picture. The field Equipment_Group has the string separated by (^)

`custom_field_enum_values_api.Get_Client_Value('EQUIGROLMW','DITCHCLEANER')`

But the API is only allowing me to pass two parameters: the first one is table_name and the second one is the database_value the output from the API is the real name, which is the value that I am looking for. I want my output to be similar to the picture in one cell such as Equiment_group field but I want the values output from the API in a single cell.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are extra two steps necessary:

1. Split the CF$_LMWEQUIMENT string into distinct tokens which can be passed to the translation function.
2. Concatenate the output from the translation function into a single string.

We can use REGEXP_SUBSTR() to achieve the first step and LISTAGG() to do the second. Here is a solution (with [a working demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=115124410610d58c48aecf2c5a99bc0e) ).

```
select t1.opportunity_no as bo_number,
        listagg(
         custom_field_enum_values_api.get_client_value('EQUIGROLMW',regexp_substr(cf$_lmwequiment,'[^\^]+', 1, level) ) 
         , ',' ) within group (order by level)
          as equiment_group,
       t1.state as status
from business_opportunity t1 
join business_opportunity_cft t2 on (t1.objkey = t2.rowkey)
connect by regexp_substr(cf$_lmwequiment,'[^\^]+', 1, level) is not null
group by t1.opportunity_no, t1.state
/
```

Once again, code like this demonstrates that the wages of shonky data modelling is shocking SQL. That's why people like me always bang on about [the importance of normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

---

My solution only addresses a scenario where's there's one row of data to be selected. It's even more complicated when multiple rows are involved. I don't have time to do a demo for that right now, but please comment me if this doesn't work for you and I'll pick this up later.